# Will the raw table ever receive fragmented IP packets?

Tags: iptables, ip, ip-fragmentation

Assume the conntrack module is loaded (thus `nf_defrag_ipv4` is loaded). Will there *ever* be a situation in which the raw table receives a fragmented packet? In particular, will a BPF rule (loaded through `xt_bpf`) like this ever return true?

```
    ldh [6]
    jset #0x1fff, match
    ret #0
match:
    ret #65535
```

I ask because I need to optimize some cBPF being used by iptables, and fragmentation checks seems like something I can get rid of, given that conntrack's fragment reassembly module hooks before anything in the raw table.